# Access Numpy Arary based on other Array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array A of size [2, 10]. I have another array B of length 10, whose values range between 0 and 1. I now want to access A, taking for each column the row specified by B, meaning:
The output should have length 10, the i-th entry in the resulting array is A[0, i] if B[i] == 0 else A[1, i].
How do I index that correcly / most elegantly?
Thanks.

Comment: `np.where(B == 0, A[0], A[1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.choose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html#numpy.choose) for that:

```
>>> a
array([[ -3,   2,   5,   0,  -2,  12,   5,  -1, -12,   5],
       [ -8, -12,  15,   6,   2,  -3,   4, -17,   0,   7]])
>>> b
array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
>>> np.choose(b, a)
array([ -8,   2,   5,   6,   2,  -3,   4, -17, -12,   7])
```

Here the first parameter `b` is the array that contains the values of the choices, and the next parameter is a 2d-array of the values per choice.

As you can see, for the indices `i` where `b[i] == 0`, then the corresponding value of the first row `a[0][i]`, and for `b[i] == 1`, we get `a[1][i]`. This can easily be generalized for more values.

or we can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and pass subarrays:

```
>>> np.where(b, a[1], a[0])
array([ -8,   2,   5,   6,   2,  -3,   4, -17, -12,   7])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work:

```
A[1][i] if B[i] == 0 else A[0][i]
```